# BVP for $y'' - 2y^3 = 0$ where $h= 0.25 , y(-1) = 0.5 y(0) = 0.5 , [-1.0]$ by using finite difference method

Tags: numerical-methods, finite-differences, numerical-calculus

find BVP for $y'' - 2y^3 = 0$ where $h= 0.25 , y(-1) = 0.5 y(0) = 0.5 , [-1.0]$ by using finite difference method.

I have been trying to solve this but I got a system of equations where my variables are more than my equations. Any help please... and can I use Gaussian elimination.

Comment: You'll want to share the discretization you came up with. Chances are you forget to include the boundary conditions in your system.

Comment: i used them (the value of y0 and y4) , but i need to know ( y1, y2 , y3 and y^3(1)) but i have three steps (j=1,2,3), i have a problem with y^3 how can i deal with it? as a Different variable right?

Comment: I wish you best of luck in your studies and endeavors.

Comment: K thank you ':)

Comment: What equations are you using to approximate $y''[t]$? You have 5 unknowns and 2 equations, you just need 3 more equations and you need to use the ODE to get those equations. For example,  $y’[t] \approx \frac{y[t+h]-y[t]}{h}$, which can be used for $t =kh$ for integers $k$.

Comment: im using y''[t] = y[t+h] - 2y[t] + y[t-h] / h^2

Comment: I see. The problem is that you are getting a system of nonlinear equations, not that you have more variables than equations. It would be easy if you were given $y[-1]$ and $y[-1+h]$ to propagate forward the update equation for $y[t+2h]$ in terms of $y[t+h]$ and $y[t]$.  One simple way is to use $y[-1]=0.5$ and play around with different values of $y[-1+h]$ to see what makes the resulting $y[0]\approx 0.5$, where $y[0]=y[-1+4h]$.

Comment: Other properties of the ODE that I notice are that if $y(t)$ is a solution over an appropriate time interval, then so is $y(-t)$. So I believe the symmetric boundary conditions mean that the true solution to the ODE is symmetric about $t=-1/2$. You could perhaps use this to justify the equation $y[-1+h]=y[-1+3h]$, although this may somewhat change the nature of the discrete time method.  I also notice that the nonlinear equation between $y[-1], y[-1+h], y[-1+2h]$ reduces to a linear equation between $y[-1+h]$ and $y[-1+2h]$ since you know $y[-1]^3=0.5^3$.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, the finite difference discretization leads to the nonlinear system
$$
\begin{cases}
y_2-2y_1+\frac 12 -2h^2y_1^3=0\\
y_3-2y_2+y_1-2h^2y_2^3=0\\
\frac 12-2y_3+y_2-2h^2y_3^3=0
\end{cases},
$$

which you can solve by a numerical method of your preference. If you use Newton's method starting from $(0,0,0)$, you'll get 6 correct digits after 5 iterations.